# get list of all lists, libraries and pages of a user

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007

Trying to get list of all lists, libraries and pages which can be accessed by a user programatically

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464984.aspx - SPWeb object Lists property. Post samples to clarify your question.